# Enter key doesnt work properly on ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

After i installed gnome tweaks and changed my theme to yaru in ubuntu 18.04 my enter key behaves weirdly,whenever i press it,it enters a equal sign before going to the next line any fixes for this ?

Comment: Have you tried to change the theme back, as a test ?

Comment: yea i did that,but doesnt work

Comment: You are not indicating in what application that happens?